# How to package and deploy a registry key with MSIX

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, msix

We have a WPF application that we're packaging as MSIX to deploy to our internal store.

Together with that app I would like to deploy a registry key (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to control the behavior of the `WebBrowser` control).

I keep finding info about how it works underneath, `Registry.dat`, which is a registry hive, inside the msix, I also found a tool (MSIXTweaker) that adds this to the msix file, but the msix file is an intermediate product, the final one being either a `msixbundle` or `msixupload`.

What is the correct way of adding a registry key to the package? Like in the `wapproj` or `appxmanifest` or as a dependency or ...?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that registry to be visible only to your application or do you need other applications from the OS to see it?

When you deploy a [registry key/value with an MSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69392940/how-to-package-and-deploy-a-registry-key-with-msix) the entry will be visible only inside the container of your application, other applications cannot use it.

The Windows Application Packaging Project template from VS does not have support for editing/adding registry in your package. For this you will need to use a tool like Advanced Installer or InstallShield, which offer much more powerful MSIX packaging options.

The MSIXTweaker tool is not intended for your purpose. We built this tool for IT professionals that need to automate certain repeatable operation over a batch of MSIX packages. It was not designed to make it easy to edit just a package.